# Operators "building" linear independant sets

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and let $T\in L(E,E)$.

Is there a condition on $T$ ensuring that:
$$
\mbox{$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^N\subseteq E$ is linearly independent} \Rightarrow
\{T(x_n)\}_{n=1}^N\cup \{x_n\}_{n=1}^N \mbox{ is a independent in $E$}?
$$

Is $T$ [mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_(mathematics)) enough for this?  Are such objects studied in the literature?

Comment: I don't think that chaotic is sufficient. There are chaotic weighted shift operators on $\ell^2$. For the standard unit vectors (sequences) $e_n$ the image $T(e_2)$ is a multiple of $e_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly I misunderstood your question, but it seems to me that an operator satisfying the condition should have $\{x, Tx\}$ linearly independent for nonzero $x$. Then the condition fails to be satisfied for $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N=\{x,Tx\}$, because its image repeats a vector, so there are no operators $T$ satisfying the condition.

If you do not like contradiction by repetitions, you can pick $x_1=x$, $x_2=x+Tx$.